# Automatically guard that all projects in a VS solution use a specific nullable reference type enabled setting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

For our VS2022 solutions (that we work on with a team) I'd like to have an automatic guard mechanism that warns the developer when they have (accidentally) added a new (C#) project that does not have the 'nullable reference type' enabled setting that our coding guidelines prescribe.

For some solutions our guideline says that nullable reference types should be enabled and for other it should be disabled.

There is probably some Roslyn analyser or FxCop nuget package that can do this nicely. A Jenkins plugin is less ideal but also acceptable.

Currently we have implemented this guard as a unit test that is aware of where it lives within the file-tree of the solution, and reads the contents of all the *.csproj files to verify the  setting, but it feels like that's not so robust (and additionally, reinventing the wheel)

Comment: What source control system are you using? Sounds like the sort of thing a commit hook (or whatever moral equivalent you have available to you) should work for.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: we use a local BitBucket server. Do you know of any specific analysers for this feature that can be run in a commit hook?

Comment: You can also try [FxCop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/net-analyzers-faq?view=vs-2022): FxCop can be used to check for violations of encoding The situation of the standard. You can create custom rules in FxCop to enforce your coding guidelines, including checking for nullable reference type settings in C# project files.